# Unbalanced data fit in gbm

Tags: machine-learning, r, gbm

I'm trying to build a model using GBM in r in order to get probability of two classes ( 'yes','no'). My data are unbalanced, and because of this I trained my model using a balanced data(undersampling the 'no' class). I trained my model With the balanced sample and then I evaluate the performance on my test sample ( 30% of the balanaced sample).

My question is:

There is any problem to predict the probability with my fit in the unbalanced sample? When I performe this, the probability distribution are equal of the probability distribution of my balanced sample, and because of this maybe my score is meaningless